# Badged control badge size

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am trying to play a bit with the badged control from Mahapps. Is it possible to change the size of the badge (not just the color/value/etc..)
Finally I am trying to do some sort of bigger pulse effect when the badge value changed, I tried the following for the color but it didn't work:

```
                 <Controls:Badged.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Controls:Badged.BadgeChanged">
                            <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard Name="AnimateVisibilityChanged">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                        From="#FFEE4709"
                                                        To="Green"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:0"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Controls:Badged.BadgeBackground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        </ColorAnimation>
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5"
                                                        From="Green"
                                                        To="Transparent"
                                                        AutoReverse="True"
                                                        BeginTime="0:0:2"
                                                        RepeatBehavior="0:0:2.5"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Controls:Badged.BadgeBackground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                        </ColorAnimation>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <EventTrigger.ExitActions>
                                <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="AnimateVisibilityChanged" />
                            </EventTrigger.ExitActions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Controls:Badged.Triggers>
```

The next step if this would work is to also increase the size more than it's already increasing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I will answer to my question:

- the animation didn't work because I used EnterActions instead of simply Actions (EventTrigger.Actions)
- To change the size of the badge when the value changes I had to use BadgeChangedStoryboard property and replace with my own:

  ```
  <SineEase x:Key="BadgeEase"
            EasingMode="EaseOut" />
  <Storyboard x:Key="BadgeChangedStoryboard">
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="2.3" />
          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource BadgeEase}"
                                KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                                Value="1" />
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
      <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                Value="2.3" />
          <EasingDoubleKeyFrame EasingFunction="{StaticResource BadgeEase}"
                                KeyTime="0:0:0.3"
                                Value="1" />
      </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
  ```

To change the size change both the easing double key frame Value